# No Simple Group of Order 1080

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I came up with what I think is a nice elementary proof, and I just want to double-check there are no mistakes:

Proof that there is no simple group $G$ of order $1080=2^33^35$.

Suppose $G$ is simple.

The candidates for the number of $5$-Sylow subgroups are $6$, $36$, and $216$.  $216$ is impossible as the $5$-Sylows would then be in the centers of their normalizers, implying the existence of a normal $5$-complement, by the Burnside transfer theorem.  $6$ is impossible as it would imply a non-trivial homomorphism from $G$ to $\frak{S}_6$ (the transitive action of $G$ on the $6$ $5$-Sylows), which is impossible as $|G|>|\frak{S}_6|$ and $G$ is simple.
Thus, a $5$-Sylow $P_5$ has a normalizer $N_5$ of order $\frac{1080}{36}=30$.  Since $P_5$ is cyclic of order $5$, ${\rm Aut}(P_5)$ is cyclic of order $4$.  Thus, the $3$-elements in $N_5$ commute with the $5$-elements.  Note that in $N_5$, the resulting cyclic subgroup of order $15$ has index $2$ and thus is normal.  The (Sylow) $3$-subgroup of $N_5$ is thus normal (and unique) as it is characteristic in a normal subgroup.

Now consider a $3$-element $z$ that centralizes a $5$-element.  (These exist in $N_5$.)  This exists in some $3$-Sylow, and in a group of order $27$ every centralizer has order at least $9$.  ($p$-groups have non-trivial centers, so non-central elements are centralized by themselves and and non-trivial element of the center.)  Thus, $|Z(z)|$ is divisible by $45$.  However, the $5$-Sylow can't be normal in $Z(z)$ as its normalizer in $G$ only has order $30$.  The only candidates for the number of $5$-Sylows in $Z(z)$ is $6$, since if it were $36$, it would be a normal subgroup (the set of all $p$-Sylows is closed under conjugation).  Thus, each $3$-element $z$ that centralizes a $P_5$ centralizes $6$ of them.

But we saw above that each $P_5$ is normalized by a unique $3$-subgroup $\langle z\rangle$ of order $3$.  We now see that each such $\langle z\rangle $ normalizes $6$ $5$-Sylows.  Since there are $36$ $5$-Sylows, there are $6$ such $\langle z\rangle $ (one-sixth as many as there are $5$-Sylow subgroups), and $G$ acts non-trivially on them by conjugation, and thus has a non-trivial homomorphism to $\frak{S}_6$.  Thus $G$ cannot be simple.

Comment: It looks OK, but you can be faster. Instead of considering the centralizer of $\langle z\rangle$, consider its normalizer. This has order a multiple of $90$, so exactly $90$ as the index cannot be $6$ or lower. But the normalizer of the Sylow $5$-subgroup in $G$ normalizes $\langle z\rangle$, so the size of the normalizer of the Sylow $5$-subgroup in $N_G(\langle z\rangle)$ is at least $30$, which leads to it being normal and your contradiction.

Comment: You can also use the fact that, if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $N_G(N_G(P))=N_G(P)$. Since $N_G(P_5)$ normalizes $z$, you know that it must be self-normalizing in $N_G(z)$.

Comment: Here is another perhaps easier approach.  As above, argue that $N_G(\langle z \rangle)$ has order $90$. ($|N_G(\langle z \rangle)|$ is divisible by 30 and 9, and cannot be a proper multiple of 90.)   A group of order 90 has a subgroup $J$ of order 45.  $J$ has a normal subgroup $P$ of order 5.  This contradicts the result that $|N_G(P)| =30$.